# Python issue with an arithmetic operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a line of Python code that doesn't work the way it should (at least to the best of my knowledge). Following is the code line:

```
print 'progress: {}%'.format((i/len(e_numbers))*100)
```

The value of `i` starts from `0` and goes up to length of `e_numbers` which is a `list`, while the length of `e_numbers` is around `17000`. But the code always prints `Progress: 0%`.

Any idea why?

Comment: `print 'progress: {}%'.format((float(i)/len(e_numbers))*100)` instead. Python 2.7 does integer division by default

Comment: Well, does dividing 5 by 6 (or 6 by 8, or 1 by 2, etc) give you a floating-point number?

Comment: `e_numbers` has no `len` if it's an integer = 17000

Comment: Is this line in some loop or just as a singular statement?

Comment: @Bazingaa it's a list. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MichalPolovka It's in a loop

Comment: Can you try putting `float(i)` and re-run your code?

Comment: @ForceBru: In python 3+, dividing 5 by 6 does give a float = `0.833333`. In python 2+ it gives 0.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Since @roganjosh answered it first, he should post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Bazingaa, the OP clearly stated that they're using Python 2.7, so for them division of two integers results in another integer.

Comment: @ForceBru: May be the above discussion will encourage the OP to update to python 3+ :)

Comment: @rootkit there is an answer that says the same thing. You should accept that, I'm not bothered :)

Comment: @Bazingaa I can't switch to python 3+ in this project since it's not up to me. Although, I use python 3+ in general, hence the mix up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, using `/` to divide two integers performs integer division by default, rounding the result down to the nearest integer value.  Thus, as long as `i` is between 0 and `len(e_numbers)`, `i/len(e_numbers)` is going to be 0.  There are two possible solutions:

1. Cast one or both operands to a float before dividing, e.g., `float(i)/len(e_numbers)`
2. Put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file so that `/` always produces a float.